# Array Slice last 1500 Array Elements - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to slice 1500 array elements from last element of a dynamic array. But array is empty after slicing.

```
   var arr = ["False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","True","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","True","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","True","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False"];

   if(arr.length > 1500) {
      sliced =  arr.slice(arr.length-1500, arr.length);
      alert("Sliced Data " + sliced);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the array in dynamically generated then you can create the array using this way easily no need to use the large element-ed array. Let's try this way-

```js
var ar = Array.from({length: 1600}, i => "False");
console.log(ar)
```

But I can see the proper sliced array after `slice`. See on console

```js
var arr = ["False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "True", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "True", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "True", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False", "False"];

if (arr.length > 1500) {
  sliced = arr.slice(arr.length - 1500, arr.length);
  console.log(sliced); // it contains 1500 elements
  console.log(arr); //it contains 1579 elements

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine. try console.log and see the array.

```js
var arr = ["False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","True","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","True","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","True","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False"];



     if(arr.length>1500)
              {
                  sliced =  arr.slice(arr.length-1500, arr.length);
                  console.log("Sliced Data  "+sliced);
                  console.log(arr.length,sliced.length)
              }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a negative value in [`.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) which will take the *last* < whatever the value is > number of entries of the array:

```js
//generate array from 1 to 1600
const arr = Array.from({length: 1600}, (_, i) => i + 1);

console.log("arr[0] :", arr[0]);
console.log("arr[1599] :", arr[1599]);

//slice to get the last 1500 items
const sliced  = arr.slice(-1500);

console.log("sliced .length :", sliced .length)
console.log("sliced [0] :", sliced [0])
console.log("sliced [1499] :", sliced [1499])
```